# Post data processing in libmicrohttpd

Tags: c, http, httprequest

I am using libmicrohttpd (http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) to implement a server which accepts a file from the client(a HTML page) and encrypt it and send it back to the client. I am making a POST request to server with the file and option whether tthe server should encrypt or decrypt the already encrypted file.

I am aware of the fact that "KEY:VALUE" pairs are used to process the POST data via a POST_PROCESSOR but i couldn't find any good supporting documentation on how to use POST_PROCESSOR to fetch the POST data from the client.

I am looking for an example on how to fetch the data being sent by the client and i thought someone could help me here.

I chose libmicrohttpd because encryption needs better performance as it takes time and implementing it in c would be a good option. Any suggestions about alternative frameworks which could be used to implement the above would also help (most probably where a java api could act as a client).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Today I did a comment in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705436/3268398):

> I'm using GNU libmicrohttpd too, and I found a simple POST demo on its
>   [repository](https://gnunet.org/svn/libmicrohttpd/doc/examples/simplepost.c).
>
> The demo is a little bit simple: it has a form that asks about your
>   name, so when you type your name and click in the "Send" button, the
>   posted data is processed in the answer_to_connection() function:

So I sent a small part from the original demo:

```
static int answer_to_connection (void *cls, struct MHD_Connection *connection,
                      const char *url, const char *method,
                      const char *version, const char *upload_data,
                      size_t *upload_data_size, void **con_cls)
{
...

  if (0 == strcmp (method, "POST"))
    {
      struct connection_info_struct *con_info = *con_cls;

      if (*upload_data_size != 0)
        {
          MHD_post_process (con_info->postprocessor, upload_data,
                            *upload_data_size);
          *upload_data_size = 0;

          return MHD_YES;
        }
      else if (NULL != con_info->answerstring)
        return send_page (connection, con_info->answerstring);
    }
...
```

I believe that this demo can help you, because I did some tests and it worked fine. =)